# Mysql Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value in function

Tags: mysql

I searched and knew this had been asked for many times but mine seems different. I'm not using `update` nor `and`. Due to the following test, I call it "in function"，and I'm really confused.

In fuction:

```
drop function if exists `login_t`;
create function `login_t`()
returns bool
begin
    declare `pw` varchar(32);
        set `pw` = '4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93';
    return if(pw, pw = MD5(CONCAT('123', '123')), false);
end;
select login_t(); -- > Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93'
```

In proc:

```
drop procedure if exists `login_t2`;
create procedure `login_t2`()
begin
    declare `pw` varchar(32);
        set `pw` = '4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93';
    select if(pw, pw = MD5(CONCAT('123', '123')), false);
end;
call login_t2(); -- 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like when you return a boolean value from a function, the values is expected to be numeric. MySQL tries to convert the first parameter of the if-function (pw) to numeric value and fails.

You can use code:

```
create function `login_t`()
returns boolean
begin
    declare `pw` varchar(32);

    set `pw` = '4297f44b13955235245b2497399d7a93';

    if (pw = MD5(CONCAT('123', '123'))) then
      return true;
    else   
      return false;
    end if;
end;
```